# Type '--2016-08-04' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, updates, hadoop

I want to install hadoop in my Ubuntu 14.04 system. Following the instruction of a blog, I need to update the "source list".

But when I input the command: `sudo apt-get update` I get errors:

```
E: Type '--2016-08-04' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list       E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

At the same time, a stop sign shows in the upper right of the menu says that:

**An error occured. Please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or run apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.**

The error message was:

```
'Unknown error: '<class 'SystemError'
E:Type '--2016-08-04' is not known on line 1 in the source list /etc/apt/sources.list.
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies"
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
--2016-08-04 21:29:00-- (try: 1) http://pastebin.com     
/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M Resolving pastebin.com (pastebin.com)...     
104.20.63.56, 104.20.64.56 Connecting to pastebin.com  
(pastebin.com)|104.20.63.56|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers. Retrying.
```

This is the beginning of the sources.list.

Comment: yes, I  input  the command : grep -rne  '--2016-08-04'  /etc/apt/  .    And I get the follows :                                                                                                                                    /etc/apt/sources.list:1:--2016-08-04 21:29:00--  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M
/etc/apt/sources.list:7:--2016-08-04 21:29:01--  (try: 2)  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M
/etc/apt/sources.list:12:--2016-08-04 21:29:03--  (try: 3)  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M
   ...
grep: /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` in an editor as a root *(e.g. type in terminal `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`)*, and replace all its content with the following

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Your problem is that in this file instead of repositorires some kind of output of a command. I have no idea how it got there, you would probably better know that.

Comment: yes ,that worked , I replace my sources.list with you  answer , restart the computer ,Then run the "sudo apt-get update" again, and there was no errors ,and it works!    Thanks very much !

Comment: @zhangwp no problem =) Btw, if you're going to edit the file: there's no need to reboot, the file being re-read on every `update`.

Comment: +1 but just to note this is using US mirror, maybe better to suggest main mirror for more widely applicable solution and also mention that partner repo etc include non-foss 3rd party apps iirc

Comment: @Zanna tbh it was just a quick answer to an easy question, and I already don't even remember where did I get the `sources.list` from. I don't actually think anybody aside of the author would ever stumble upon this question *(as in, not the problem, but this particular post on the site)*. The proper solution would probably be to close it as a duplicate of, say, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories).

Comment: @Zanna Ah, yeah, IIRC this answer *(as for, why I didn't vote to close as a dup)* was in particular stimulated by the fact that the question itself was mangled, and it wasn't obvious what the problem author has suffered of. So, when I figured it out, it seemed to me funny enough that I get the idea of what was the problem about, so I posted an answer. And in particular it was for other peoples to not spend their time on this question anymore.

Comment: My philosophy is that every post is forever and should be as good as possible :) If you want to improve your answer, then I would say maybe not worth duping it (now the post is linked on this page anyway) but if not, then I guess I'll VTC